# Быстрое возведение в степень BigDecimal

Tags: java

Реализую алгоритм "слева направо" ([Алгоритмы быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C))

```
public class BigAlgebra {
    BigDecimal fastPow(BigDecimal num, int pow) {
        if (pow == 0) return BigDecimal.valueOf(1.);        //проверка нулевой степени
        String BYNPOW = Integer.toString(pow, 2);           //представление степени двоичным числом
        BigDecimal res = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);             //инициализация результата НУЛЕМ
        for (int i = BYNPOW.length() - 1; i <= 0; i++) {    //цикл перебора от СТАРШЕГО бита к МЛАДШЕМУ
            if (BYNPOW[i] == 1) {                           //TODO
                res = res.multiply(res).multiply(num);
            } else res = res.multiply(res);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigAlgebra cadabra = new BigAlgebra();
        System.out.println(cadabra.fastPow(BigDecimal.valueOf(3), 5));

    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку: `Error:(7, 17) java: array required, but java.lang.String found`. Подскажите как в контексте заменить матричное обращение к строке ?

Comment: Здесь точно ошибка `i++`. А еще есть константы `BigDecimal.ZERO`, `BigDecimal.ONE`

Comment: Error:(7, 17) java: array required, but java.lang.String found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно по вашей ошибке:
в Java к символу в строке нельзя обратиться по индексу в квадратных скобках, как к элементу массива (в отличие от C/C++ и других языков). К тому же, символ строки нужно сравнивать с символом `'1'`, а не с числом 1. Поэтому вместо

```
if (BYNPOW[i] == 1) {
```

должно быть

```
if (BYNPOW.charAt(i) == '1') {
```

После этого исправления код компилируется и запускается: https://ideone.com/irAPK4

Еще одна проблема: по логике ваш код должен проходить с конца строки до ее начала, но цикл прерывается на первой же итерации, т.к. исходное значение `i` заведомо не проходит условие цикла `i <= 0`. Цикл должен быть таким:

```
for (int i = BYNPOW.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Т.е. идти от последнего символа, пока индекс больше или равен нулю, на каждом шаге индекс уменьшать на 1.